# MY app is being force Closed on emulator. its based on samlpe calculaor code found on a russian website on google

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am a totally noob on android app coding. I have tried to make this project with the help of [This Site][1], There is no error on eclipse window and and there is some warning on lint window. like hardcoded string and padding related. I can export apk. but when i tri to run my apk on real device or in emulator i face force close. logcat has been provided at below.

```
08-24 08:33:37.852: D/dalvikvm(1130): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 55K, 4% free 3333K/3452K, paused 34ms, total 36ms
    08-24 08:33:37.862: D/AndroidRuntime(1130): Shutting down VM
    08-24 08:33:37.862: W/dalvikvm(1130): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a1aba8)
    08-24 08:33:37.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1130): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    08-24 08:33:37.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1130): Process: com.hkb, PID: 1130
    08-24 08:33:37.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1130): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hkb/com.hkb.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.hkb.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener
    08-24 08:33:37.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
    08-24 08:33:37.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
    08-24 08:33:37.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    08-24 08:33:37.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    08-24 08:33:37.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    08-24 08:33:37.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    08-24 08:33:37.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    08-24 08:33:37.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    08-24 08:33:37.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    08-24 08:33:37.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    08-24 08:33:37.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    08-24 08:33:37.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    08-24 08:33:37.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1130): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.hkb.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener
    08-24 08:33:37.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at com.hkb.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
    08-24 08:33:37.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    08-24 08:33:37.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    08-24 08:33:37.882: E/AndroidRuntime(1130):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
```

Here is my MainActivity.Java

```
package com.hkb;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


@SuppressLint("Registered")
public abstract class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    EditText et1;
    EditText et2;
    EditText et3;
    EditText et4;
    EditText et5;
    EditText et6;
    Button btn1;
    Button btn2;
    Button btn3;
    TextView tv1;
    TextView tv8;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
            et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);
            et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et3);
            et4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et4);
            et5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et5);
            et6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et6);

            btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
            btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
            btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);


            tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
            tv8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv8);

            // set a listener
            btn1.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) this);
            btn2.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) this);
            btn3.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) this);
         //   btnDiv.setOnClickListener(this);

          }
    public void onClick(View v) {//public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        float num1 = 0;
        float num2 = 0;
        float num3 = 0;
        float SCut = 0;
        float SDec = 0;
        float Deco = 0;
        float Tp = 0;
        float FT = 0;
        float BC = 0;
        float Tp1 = 0;
        float FT2 = 0;
        float BC3 = 0;
        float GSM = 0;
        float Tem1 = 0;
        float result = 0;

        // check if the fields are empty
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(et1.getText().toString())
            || TextUtils.isEmpty(et2.getText().toString())
           ||TextUtils.isEmpty(et3.getText().toString())) {
          return;
        }
        num1 = Float.parseFloat(et1.getText().toString());
        num2 = Float.parseFloat(et2.getText().toString());
        num3 = Float.parseFloat(et2.getText().toString());
        SCut = (float) (num1 + num2 + 1.5);
        SDec = num2 + num3;
        Deco = SDec + SDec;
        Tp = Float.parseFloat(et4.getText().toString());
        FT = Float.parseFloat(et5.getText().toString());
        BC = Float.parseFloat(et6.getText().toString());

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn1:
            Tp1 = Tp * 1;
            FT2 = (float) (FT * 1.5);
            BC3 = BC * 1;
            GSM = Tp1 + FT2 + BC3;
            Tem1 = SCut * SDec * GSM;
          result = Tem1/1550 * 2;
          break;
        case R.id.btn2:
            Tp1 = Tp * 1;
            FT2 = (float) (FT * 3);
            BC3 = BC * 2;
            GSM = Tp1 + FT2 + BC3;
            Tem1 = SCut * SDec * GSM;
          result = Tem1/1550 * 2;
          break;
        case R.id.btn3:
            Tp1 = Tp * 1;
            FT2 = (float) (FT * 4.5);
            BC3 = BC * 3;
            GSM = Tp1 + FT2 + BC3;
            Tem1 = SCut * SDec * GSM;
          result = Tem1/1550 * 2;
          break;}
        // form the output line
        tv1.setText("Weight = " + result + "Gram");
        tv8.setText("Dekol = " + Deco);
      }



    // @Override
    //public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    //}

}
```

Layout ActivityMain.Xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Enter Details of Box"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Length"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Breath"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Height"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:paddingLeft="38dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textStyle="bold" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:paddingLeft="38dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:paddingLeft="38dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="30dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Top"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:text="Froot"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:text="Back"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:paddingLeft="38dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:paddingLeft="38dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:paddingLeft="38dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="Weight = 1234 Gm"
            android:textColor="@color/green"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:text="Dekol = 0.00"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="For 3 Ply" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="For 5 Ply" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="For 7 Ply" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginLeft="215dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/reload"
        android:height="48dp"
        android:minHeight="24dp"
        android:minWidth="24dp"
        android:width="48dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hkb"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.hkb.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>


[1]: http://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/complete-list/225-lesson-19-creating-a-simple-calculator.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that your log says:

> Caused by: `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.hkb.MainActivity` cannot be cast to `android.view.View$OnClickListener`

You are importing the wrong `OnClickListener` class. You are importing `android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener`, but trying to cast your Activity as an `android.view.View.OnClickListener`.

Update your imports to use `android.view.View.OnClickListener` and it should work.